# Extent of verification of household-name physical concepts?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, speed-of-light, climate-science

I was listening to some news coverage of the IPCC's newest report, which included a statement that "the evidence that climate change is real is now provided by over 14,000 studies worldwide."

I'm sure many of those studies are actually about questions other than "is climate change a thing?" But I'm now curious about what the most studied phenomena in other disciplines are, and how the extent of the scrutiny of climate change stacks up.

To wit:

1. How many studies are there that provide evidence for the existence of gravity?
2. How many for the speed of light?
3. How many for the existence of electromagnetism?

I'm curious about where Climate Change is on the scale of things the scientific community has really put effort into studying over the years.

Some ground rules:

1. I'm talking about academic-grade studies (though for stuff happening before peer review was such a worldwide phenomenon they needn't be journal-published), and related activities. Inventions that rely on a theory don't count for this, or we'd be in the billions (at least) before I finished typing this up.
2. To follow the IPCC report's maths, 'provides evidence for' means that either the research question was directly aimed at the phenomenon, or that the experimental design relies on the phenomenon functioning as understood and it would be recognizable if existing knowledge of these phenomena being incorrect was contributing to unexpected results.
3. If you're ballparking your estimate, please show your work so that I can compare estimation methods before determining which answer to accept.

Comment: A lot more that 14,000 people would agree that the sky is blue. Does that make them all wrong, simply because they agree? Sorry, but you can't use logical reasoning to persuade people who don't understand the words "logical" and "reasoning."

Comment: @alephzero To clarify: I'm not asking you "How do I convince my folks, who are hellbent on denialism." I'm asking for contextualization of a claim about the IPCC AR6, and how such a measure compares to other things in the scientific realm.

Comment: "Inventions that rely on a theory don't count for this" what does that mean?

Comment: @fqq E.g. the fact that pumped hydro storage works (because water at higher elevation has potential energy due to gravity) is arguably evidence that gravity exists. But I'm looking for a count of experimental studies.

Comment: If the folks downvoting would like to suggest changes, I'm open to them.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII First of all, welcome to Physics SE! I suppose the reason for the downvotes is that your question is rather vague (in that it includes multiple questions) and not really about a physics concept. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guides for [on](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)- and [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions.

Comment: If questions about scholarship about Physics are off topic for here, then I'll accept the close vote.

Answer (score 1):

The 14000 studies are very recent, gravity and the speed of light and electromagnetism are proved again and again in many classrooms and uni courses.
climat change is not explained  by one single observation, but you should try to show your family the increase of Co2 and average temperature over the last 50 to 100 years.